# optimizer refuses to use the index

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(cfe, 6) */
      dpd.f_p_descr,
      ef.t_a_code,
      pd.p_name,
      ef.t_q
 FROM e_fact ef
INNER JOIN d_dim dd
   ON ef.t_d_key = dd.d_key
INNER JOIN f_e cfe
   ON ef.ref_id = cfe.t_id
  AND ef.r_version = cfe.t_version
INNER JOIN d_dim dpd
   ON dpd.d_key = ef.d_key
INNER JOIN p_dim pd
   ON pd.p_key = ef.b_p_key
INNER JOIN r_dim rd
   ON rd.r_key = ef.t_r_key
INNER JOIN f_t_dim ftd
   ON ftd.t_key = cfe.t_key
WHERE dd.d_value = '19-OCT-2012'
  AND dpd.f_d = 'XYZ'
  AND ftd.s_id IN (201, 209)
  AND rd.r_n = 'ABC'
```

I got this query from production, problem is optimizer refuses to use the index on `f_e` even when the hint is added (`/*+ index(e.c_fact_idx12) */`. What should be my approach and what all things I need to check for this. Is there any other way to tune this query? New to query tuning so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `e.c_fact_idx12`, but the table alias `e` is not defined anywhere in the query !

Comment: e is schema name. what it should be <tablename>.<indexname> or <schema name>.<indexname>?